# generic programming in java with dynamic nature and fully customizable

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am working on an engineering data presentation and management project. 
The nature of our project should be customizable because we might have some similar entities with few more or less attributes. for example product A has 2 additional attributes like productSize and productionDate compared to Product B, and there might be 100 different products. A different project or client might use any product and also define new products.

Is there any design pattern which could be used to consider everything as generic type or dynamic object so that we don't have specific entities for all actual types and we just have things like Type, BaseType, Property, Feature. I have seen some patterns like Dynamic Object Model which intend to tackle same concerns but I'm not sure if they actually work in real world projects or not. 
Our technology is Java and Spring to make a we application and a 3 tier architecture.

Comment: Is your manager technically proficient? You should probably ask them.

Comment: You mean that instead of a Person class with String fields like "firstName" and "lastName" you will have a Type named "Person" linked to two Property (named "firstname" and "lastname") linked to a Type called "String" ?

Comment: Rather than asking us, it might make more sense for you to go back and ask your boss for clarification

Comment: Never heard of `inheritance`?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design idea IMO.

Comment: haven't you heard about generic database design for example? they try to make the design as simple as possible so that when you wanna add a new functionality in the system you don't need to add more database tables or entities. Now I need a professional comment or guide. Specially about application tier. Of course he is not a programmer but he has heard something and he is my BOSS! you know :(

Comment: Maybe you could store all your objects in your database as XML.  There are various tools for serialising and deserialising objects to and from XML.  Or you could use JSON.

Comment: what do you mean @j.con?

Comment: I disagree with those voting to close this as "too broad". It's a question about a design pattern (or anti-pattern) with a well-known answer that @Kayaman has given a good answer to. I could see an argument, perhaps, that it might belong on programmers rather than here.

Comment: Maybe I am missing the big picture here, but if he doesn't want 20-30 different classes and wants 5 or 6 generic classes, that is where `abstract` classes come into play with `Class<T>`. Read up on `Generic Types` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, no he is not a software engineer but he is a good engineer and he has modeled the problem in his mind this way. Actually it looks great but as Kayaman told it is an anti pattern and in most cases should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a surprisingly common, and an extremely bad idea. Sounds like you're heading towards the [Inner Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) anti pattern.

It seems good when you hear it for the first time (or if you're a manager), but the result is a system that tries to do everything, but ends up doing nothing well.

The database becomes very inefficient and corruption prone as well. I've had the unfortunate privilege to see this in action.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, that's the reason he thinks this design type will help and we can do whatever we like. but how can I prove that it doesn't work? I have not ever heard and tried something like this and I don't wanna say NO without any reasoning. And I'm more interested in disadvantages in application tier.

Comment: @sina Start by showing him that wikipedia page. Warn him of problems with maintenance and performance, as well as difficulty of developing.

Comment: But I also found this as a design pattern " Dynamic Object Model" and here is a link to that. [link](http://hillside.net/plop/plop2k/proceedings/Riehle/Riehle.pdf)

Comment: @sina Yes, then you can show him the "Disadvantages" part of that paper. But it's your choice, maybe it'll fit for you, maybe you get it just right. Or maybe a few years from now you'll be thinking "damnit, that Kayaman character sure was right about how horrible this is". Anyways, I advise you to be critical towards this pattern even if you do implement it. There are advantages, and disadvantages. I only saw the disadvantages.

Comment: @sina So, how did it end? :)

Comment: I avoided "Dynamic Object Model" or whatever it is called and implemented the whole software based on normal patterns. But I did it that flexible that its user can define and change system properties and types. for example I have entities like Property, Value, Type ... Maybe close to sharepoint ideas

Comment: for example instead of defining an Entity called 'Manufacturer', a user creates it in the system (create new Property form) and  assigns properties which have been created before to that form and sets initial value for each property and so on.